# Pose Goal as Motion Plan Request

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gone through the moveit_msgs and I have seen the Motion Plan Request.

My question is, how can we specify a pose goal in the motion plan request? Is it possible to set a simple pose goal as shown in the moveit tutorials?

Also in the motion plan request message, there is a goal_constraints which further contains position_constraints. What is this constraint and where could it be used?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253025/pose-goal-as-motion-plan-request/) by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface` module is usually used to generate `MotionPlanRequests` for simple pose goals.

If you look at its implementation [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1092), you will see this simply creates Position and Orientation goal constraints out of the requested pose. It basically creates a small target volume (.1mm^3) out of the position to create a position constraint and adds axis tolerances of .001rad and the provided orientation as an orientation constraint.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on 2017-01-27**:
I just want to make sure I understand that correctly. So for example if my pose goal is at x = 0.5m, y = 0.8m and z = 0.4m, and if I am not concerned with the orientation, it will make a volume of (0.1mm^3) keeping that (x,y,z) point as the centre?

**Comment by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on 2017-01-27**:
The `moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface` method that you mentioned has to be used with the `kinematics_constraints` package right? How can I specify the pose goal if I wish to use the service `GetMotionPlan`?